# Are there infinitely many zeroes of $\sum_{r = 1}^{n-1} \mu(r)\gcd(n,r) $?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

Let $\mu(n)$ be the Möbius function and $S(x)$ be the number of positive integers $n \le x$ such that

$$
\sum_{r = 1}^{n-1} \mu(r)\gcd(n,r) = 0
$$

My experimental data for $n \le 6 \times 10^5 $seems to suggest that the number of solutions $\le x$ is growing at about

$$
S(x) \sim (\zeta(2)-1)\sqrt{x}
$$
Is there any explanation for this? The square may come from the growth rate of the Mertens function $M(n) = \sum_{r \le n}\mu(r)$ while the appearance $\zeta(2)$ may be due to the fact that it appears in many sums involving the Pillai function $P(n) = \sum_{r \le n} \gcd(n,r)$.

I also observed that $200$ out of the $230$ zeroes for $n \le 1.3 \times 10^5$, were primes which indicate that the zeroes might be dominated by primes. For a prime $p$, $\sum_{r = 1}^{p-1} \mu(r)\gcd(p,r) = M(p-1)$ so I guess it is more likely that a sequence of $\pm 1$ adds to to $0$ than a sequence of integers of higher absolute value.

[image]

**Updated** with calculations for $n \le 6 \times 10^5$

FYI: The question was [posted in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296846/are-there-infinitely-many-zeroes-of-sum-r-1n-1-mur-gcdn-r). It got votes but no answers and comments suggested that this hard. Hence I am posting it in MO.

Comment: For contemplating heuristics, it might be useful to note that \begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \mu(r)\gcd(n,r) &= \sum_{r=1}^{n-1} \mu(r) \sum_{d\mid \gcd(n,r)} \phi(d) \\
&= \sum_{d\mid n} \phi(d) \sum_{\substack{1\le r\le n-1 \\ d\mid r}} \mu(r) \\
&= \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d<n}} \phi(d)\mu(d) \sum_{\substack{1\le s< n/d \\ \gcd(d,s)=1}} \mu(s).
\end{align*}